# How do I force Google Play Store to download new apps on a roaming mobile connection?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, 7.0-nougat, roaming

I am often on a roaming mobile connection, and I have found that Google Play Store does not allow you to install apps while roaming. Clicking the "Install" button puts the app in a "Downloading..." state, but doesn't progress until you switch to a non-roaming connection (mobile or wifi). How do I force the Google Play Store to download the app while roaming? This issue occurs on and may be specific to Android 7.0.

Comment: Which OS? Are other apps able to access internet while roaming? Is the problem only with Play Store?

Comment: Saw the issue with clean installs of Android 7.0 and 6.0.1. Yes, other apps can access the network while roaming; the issue is specific to the Play Store.

Comment: With Nougat it is a known [issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/EPdFg2rZ8Mk;context-place=topicsearchin/nexus/category$3Aconnecting-to-networks-and-devices). Haven't heard of it with 6.0.1. can you do a clean install again and see?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Do you know if an issue has been opened on the Android tracker? I can't do another install with 6.0.1 right now (I've already reinstalled everything with 7.0), but I'll see if I can reproduce it later.

Comment: Is mobile network data connection enabled when in roaming mode? I remember an option in the network settings that disables data connections when roaming.

Comment: @Robert yes, it is. Other apps can use the network without issue.

Comment: The bug has been reported to the tracker [#224209](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224209). Moreover, it has occured since Android N dev. preview (refer to [#211038](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211038)). /cc @beeshyams